# Can the Virtual File System In Service Stack Be configured not not treat files with multiiple dots as directories?

Tags: servicestack, angular-cli

I'm attempting to serve an angular spa from embedded resources using the ServiceStack Virtual file system.

This appears to be mostly working, however many of my generated files include two dots in the file name like:
`inline.bundle.js`

I expected that would be served from:

`host:port/inline.bundle.js`

but it is actually served from

`host: port/inline/bundle.js`

The virtual filesystem appears to namespace based on the dot. Is there a way to configure it other wise so multiple dots in the last file are not interpretted as directories?

I'm using the angualr-cli to build the app, and it does not expose a way to modify the webpack config generating the bundles, otherwise I would just modify the file names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that Embedded Resources don't include paths when the file is embedded so a file in a folder like `/inline/bundle.js` is embedded with the same resource name that `/inline.bundle.js` is, i.e: `AssemblyNamespace.inline.bundle.js` and it's up to ServiceStack's [ResourceVirtualDirectory](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/1a00939d969e0c726d6fc8befbab84be44264dc1/src/ServiceStack/VirtualPath/ResourceVirtualDirectory.cs#L73) to use common heuristics to predict what the folder is.

You can force the `ResourceVirtualPathProvider` to treat a file by specifying it in:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig {
    EmbeddedResourceTreatAsFiles = { "inline.bundle.js" }
});
```